# How to keep my users anonymous with webrtc?

Tags: node.js, security, ip, webrtc, openvidu

I need to implement video call in my application, then I discovered webrtc, and simple-peer for nodejs.
I just have one problem, because it's peer to peer, I suppose the users aren't anonymous, they can get their ip each others.

I know facebook, amazon chime use webrtc, how do they hide those ip ? Do they pass the stream through a server? Use turn server ? 
Would openvidu hide ip ? 
Or just can I simply for each video room create peer in nodejs process, and connect to every user and distribute the video ?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In peer-to-peer mode, you can ensure the IP addresses of the peers aren't revealed by setting up and forcing the use of TURN server (using the `iceTransportPolicy` option of [`relay`](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/webrtc.html#dom-rtcicetransportpolicy-relay) in the `RTCPeerConnection()` constructor).

Alternatively, using an intermediary media server (e.g. an SFU or a MCU) would also achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thank you so much ;) Do you have an example of configuration ? Thanks ;) because I must modify for npm simple-peer

Comment: Assuming this is about https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer, then this would be expressed as
`new Peer({config:{iceTransportPolicy: 'relay'}})`